# chrome, css applies only after refresh

Tags: java, html, css

I am  a Java developer and have little knowledge of JavaScript and CSS.
So if I am asking a dumb question then please guide me.

After Login, when I see dashboard in that case,  the words "Configuration Wizard" are not displayed in the proper place.
Once the page is refreshed then it displays.

I checked in developer tools, and have seen that "Configuration Wizard" is displayed but it is behind menu bar, in dev tools if I remove menubar black color then I can see "Configuration Wizard" word present there.

Before Refresh
[image]

After Refresh.
[image]

I have pasted complete CSS because not sure which class might giving side behaviour

### CSS used

```
body, html {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Segoe UI, sans-serif !important;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #d4d6d7;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    color: #494949 !important;
}
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 14px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    height: 6px;
    border: 4px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    background-clip: padding-box;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), inset 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    display: none;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
    background-color: transparent;
}
button::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
}
textarea {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
input[type="text"], 
input[type="password"] {
    -webkit-appearance: none !important;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 1px 3px;
    resize: none;
    border: 1px solid #d7dadf;
    border-top-color: #c7cacf;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 2px;
    height: 26px;
    line-height: 26px;
}
input[type="text"]:focus, 
input[type="password"]:focus {
    border-color: #83bde9;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #b3edff;
}
button {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 6px 15px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid #e3e6e8;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d3d6d8;
    background: #BEC7C7;
    color: #333;
}
button.ipocc-btn-main {
    border: 1px solid #171d29;
    background: #2f343a;
    color: #fff;
}

#tableData .btn { 
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid #e3e6e8;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d3d6d8;
    background: #BEC7C7;
    color: #333;
}

select {
    height: 26px;
    border: 1px solid #d7dadf;
}
.ipocc-app-menu {
    background: #2f343a;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 7px 1px #808488;
    /* padding: 0 20px; */
}
.ipocc-app-menu > div {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1060px;
    background: url(../images/avaya_logo.png) left center no-repeat;
    height: 48px;
    padding-left: 52px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.ipocc-app-menu > div > div {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 48px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-left: 1px solid #4f545a;
    padding: 0 10px;
    float: left;
}
.ipocc-app-menu > div > div:hover {
    background-color: #545d63;
}
.ipocc-app-menu > div > div.ipocc-rmi {
    float: right;
}
#m3, #m4 {
    width: 40px;
    height: 48px;
    padding: 0;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-left: 0;
}
#m0 {
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: #545d63;
    height: 48px;
    border-left: none;
}
#m0:hover {
    background: #545d63;
}
#m0 > span {
    display: block;
    line-height: normal;
    padding-top: 10px;
    color: #ddd;
    font-size: 12px;
}
#m0 > em {
    display: block;
    line-height: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    color: #fff;
}
#m1 {
    border-left-color: #6f747a;
}
#m4 {
    //background-image: url(../images/user.png);
}
#m3 {
    //background-image: url(../images/help.png);
}
.ipocc-popup {
    border: none;
    margin-left: 1px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
}
.ipocc-popup > a {
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 6px 15px;
    line-height: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #494949;
    display: block;
}
.ipocc-popup > a:hover {
    background: #dcebf0;
}
#p1, #p2 {
    display: none;
}
.ipocc-app-title {




    padding: 0 20px;
    max-width: 1020px;
    /* height: 50px; */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    /* margin-top: -20px; */
    /* margin-bottom: 100px; */
    /* margin-right: 150px; */
    margin-left: 100px;
}
.ipocc-app-title h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 10px;
    color: #626a6f;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #bcc5c9;
}
.ipocc-app-view {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-left: 120px;
}
.ipocc-app-view > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #939698;
}
.ipocc-app-view > div > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    //overflow-y: auto;
    height:480px;
}
.ipocc-scroll {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height:480px;
}
.ipocc-app-view.ipocc-view-edit > div > div:first-child {
    bottom: 50px;
}
.ipocc-app-view > div > div .ipocc-view-footer {
    display: none;
}
.ipocc-view-edit > div > div.ipocc-view-footer {
    display: block;
    top: auto;
    height: 50px;
    background: #e3e6e8;
    border-top: 1px solid #d3d6d8;
}
.ipocc-view-footer button {
    min-width: 90px;
    margin: 10px 0 0 30px;
}
.ipocc-view-content {
    padding: 20px 30px 0 30px;
  //panchh  overflow: auto;
}
.ipocc-warn {
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #f0f0d0;
    background: #ffffd8 url(../images/warning.png) 10px 8px no-repeat;
    padding-left: 35px;
    display: none;
}
.ipocc-error {
    padding: 5px 400px;
    margin:0px 0px 5px 0px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #f0f0d0;
    background: #ffffd8 url(../images/error.gif) 10px 5px no-repeat;
    padding-left: 35px;
    display: none;
}
.ipocc-dbwarn {
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #f0f0d0;
    background: #ffffd8 url(../images/warning.png) 10px 8px no-repeat;
    padding-left: 35px;
}
#uploadPanel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 150px;
    background: #e3e6e8;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 #ddd;
}
.uploadField {
    width: 250px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #d9d9d9;
    /* margin: 16px 10px 15px 30px; */
    padding: 2px;
    background: #fff;
}
#uploadAction {
   /*  margin: 16px 0; */
}
#uploadDetails {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 150px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
   //PANCH display: none;
}
.ipocc-upload-steps {
    width: 58%;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 10px 0 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top: 20px;
    display:none;
}
.ipocc-upload-step {
    margin: 0 0 13px 0;
    position: relative;
}
.ipocc-upload-step > div:first-child {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 3px;
    width: 19px;
    height: 19px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 19px;
    color: #bbb;
}
.ipocc-upload-step > div:last-child {
    margin-left: 30px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #bbb;
}
.ipocc-upload-step.status-ok > div:last-child,
.ipocc-upload-step.status-busy > div:last-child {
    color: #444;
}
.ipocc-upload-step.status-err > div:last-child {
    color: #d44;
}
.ipocc-upload-step.status-ok > div:first-child {
    border-color: #3c4;
    color: transparent;
}
.ipocc-upload-step.status-ok > div:first-child:before {
    content: "\2713";
    color: #3c4;
    font-weight: normal;
    display: block;
    line-height: 19px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.ipocc-upload-step.status-err > div:first-child {
    border-color: #e55;
    color: transparent;
}
.ipocc-upload-step.status-err > div:first-child:before {
    content: "!";
    color: #e55;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
    line-height: 19px;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
.ipocc-upload-step.status-busy > div:first-child {
    border-color: transparent;
    color: transparent;
}
.ipocc-upload-step.status-busy > div:first-child:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 19px;
    height: 19px;
    background: url("../images/busy.gif") center center no-repeat;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.ipocc-upload-step > div:last-child h4 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.ipocc-upload-step > div:last-child > p {
    margin: 2px 0 0 0;
    display: none;
}
.ipocc-upload-cfg {
    width: 40%;
    white-space: pre-line;
    font-family: Consolas, Monaco, monospace;
    float: left;
    padding: 20px 0 0 20px;
    border-left: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    display:none;
}
#manualView {
    display: none;
}
.ipocc-flow-panel {
    padding: 5px 0;
}
.ipocc-flow-panel > h2 {
    margin: -10px 0 15px 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #aaa;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.ipocc-field {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 200px;
}
.ipocc-flow-panel > .ipocc-field {
    margin: 0 25px 10px 0;
}
.ipocc-field > span {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
.ipocc-field > div {
    display: block;
}
.ipocc-field > div > input[type="text"],
.ipocc-field > div > input[type="password"],
.ipocc-field > div > select {
    width: 100%;
}
.ipocc-field > em {
    display: block;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 11px;
}
.ipocc-field > em.warn,
.ipocc-field > em.err {
    color: #c00;
}
input[type="text"].err,
input[type="password"].err {
    border: 1px solid #c00;
}

.ipocc-flow-panel {
//panchborder-top: 1px solid #ddd;

}
.ipocc-flow-panel:first-child {
    border-top: none;
    //panchpadding-top: 0;
}
#testIPOCon {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
#testIPOCon > div > button {
    height: 26px;
    line-height: 26px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
#agentSetupActions {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
#agentSetupActions > div > button {
    min-width: 80px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    height: 26px;
    line-height: 26px;
    padding: 0;
}
#agentSetupPanel {
    display: none;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}
#agentSetupPanel > button {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.ipocc-grid {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.ipocc-grid > div {
    display: table-row;
}
.ipocc-grid > div:hover {
    background: #F0F6FF;
}
.ipocc-grid > div > span {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 4px 15px 4px 0;
}
.ipocc-grid > div > span:last-child {
    padding-right: 0;
}
.ipocc-grid input {
    width: 150px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.ipocc-grid select {
    vertical-align: top;
}
.ipocc-grid > div:first-child {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #93cdff;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.ipocc-grid > div:first-child:hover {
    background: #fff;
}
.deletebutton {
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    background: transparent url(../images/delete.png) center center no-repeat;
    border-color: transparent;
}
.updatebutton {
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    background: transparent url(../images/update.png) center center no-repeat;
    border-color: transparent;
}
#uploadView {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
.busy {
    background-image: url(../images/busy.gif);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#ipocc-upload-details {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #494949;
    margin: 20px 0 0px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 20px;
    background-color: #f2f3f4;
   //PANCH display: none;
}
.ipocc-expand {
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    background: url(../images/expand.png) left 8px center no-repeat;
}
.ipocc-collapse {
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    background: url(../images/collapse.png) left 8px center no-repeat;
}
#ipocc-upload-logs {
    font-family: Consolas, Monaco, monospace;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: none;
    background: #f2f3f4;
    padding: 20px;
}
#ipocc-upload-logs p {
    margin: 0 0 7px 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#ipocc-upload-logs em {
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #c00;
}
.ipocc-dlg-bg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    z-index: 500;
}
.ipocc-glass {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #73808c;
    //opacity: 0.5;
    z-index: 499;
    display: none;
}
#dlgUploadConfigOk {
    display: none;
}
#dlglogout {
    display: none;
}
#dlgConnectionSuccess {
    display: none;
}
#dlgConnectionFailure {
    display: none;
}
#dlgRebootSuccess {
    display: none;
}
#dlgRebootFailure {
    display: none;
}
#dlgConfirmMessage {
    display: none;
}
#dlgMessage {
    display: none;
}
#dlgDBMessage {
    display: none;
}
#dlgTestConnectionMessage {
    display: none;
}
.ipocc-dlg-bg > div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
.ipocc-dlg {
    text-align: left;
    background: #eaeced;
    width: 350px;
    box-shadow: 0 7px 15px #80898f;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
    position: relative;
}
.ipocc-dlg > h3 {
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 15px 20px 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dadcdd;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #676a6f;
    margin: 0;
}
.ipocc-dlg > p {
    text-align: right;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    margin: 0;
}
.ipocc-dlg > p > button {
    width: auto;
    padding: 5px 25px;
    min-width: 80px;
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;
}
.ipocc-dlg > div {
    margin: 15px 20px 0 20px;
}
.ipocc-dlg > div > p {
    margin: 7px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#logsView {
   //panchdisplay: none;
}
.ipocc-field > div > input[type="checkbox"],
.ipocc-field > div > label,
.ipocc-flow-panel > h2 > input[type="checkbox"],
.ipocc-flow-panel > h2 > label {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.ipocc-field > div > label,
.ipocc-flow-panel > h2 > label {
    display: pointer;
    margin-left: 3px;
}
#logsView .ipocc-flow-panel > .ipocc-field {
    margin: 0 15px 5px 0;
}
.selected li {
  background-color: red;
}
.fontbold{
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

### HTML used

```
<div class='col-xs-7'>
      <angled-nav-bar affixed='affixed' brand='brand' 
         help='help' inverse='inverse' menus='menus' navfn='navfn(action)'>
      </angled-nav-bar>    
</div>
<div class="ipocc-app-title">
       <h1>Configuration Wizard</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Check the padding to body before and after refresh. Generally for fixed navbar padding-top is set so that the content appears below the navbar.

Answer (score 0):

Usually if you display the right styling after a refresh it's a problem of browser caching. But usually after the first refresh you should display the right style every time.

You can try to delete the cache of your browser.